# How to invoke Asymptote from an older version of TeXLive (2020), without it fishing files from another newer version (2023)?

Tags: texlive, asymptote, texworks

In one of my files I included the `asymptote` package for making interactive graphs. I installed the TeXLive 2020 distribution on my PC and everything worked perfectly. However, I recently decided to also install the TeXLive 2023 version, keeping it separate from the previous TeXLive 2020, so that I can choose which one to use at will (i.e. in two different paths: `C:\texlive\2020` and `C:\texlive\2023` on Windows). The problem is that, using the most recent one, the compiler crashes, outputting the following error message: `freeglut (asy): Unable to create OpenGL 4.0 context`. Documenting myself, it should stem from the fact that my hardware does not support that version of OpenGL, and I can accept this because my computer is quite old. The point is that if I now try to recompile it using the TeXLive 2020 version it still gives me an error (which didn't happen at the beginning of the story)! However, the message from the output console is different:

```
C:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist\asymptote/plain_pens.asy: 333.39: no matching variable 'byteinv'
C:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist\asymptote/plain.asy: 312.16: no matching variable '_schur'
C:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist\asymptote/plain.asy: 326.16: no matching variable '_schur'
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1: asy main-*.asy
```

So it seems that somehow asymptote is calling up some version 2023 files anyway.
Suggestions on how to fix the problem, keeping both versions of TeXLive? This is my MWE (called `main.tex`), which is run from command Prompt with `C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\asy.exe main-*.asy` from inside its directory:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
    import three;
    surface cube = unitcube;
    draw(cube, grey);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: normally texlive applications set their paths relative to their location so calling the 2020 binary is enough, but you may have set some 2023 paths in the environment, also it is better (for tex and I assume for asy) to set the PATH to \texlive\2020\bin\win32 then just call asy rather than call it via the full path so that any programs it calls internally pick up the right PATH

Comment: You are right. If I give priority to `C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32` instead of `C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows` in my environment variables, or if I delete the second path directly, then everything works by simply calling `asy main-*.asy` from the command prompt. However, I would like both paths to be in my PATH, with precedence to to the 2023 version, so as to always compile with the updated distribution (in case I don't need asymptote). Moreover, giving precedence to one path or the other would only have the effect of moving the problem from one version to another, without solving it completely.

Comment: switching the path is the documented way to switch between texlive installations, you don't have to change your global environment you can do it in a batch file (or shell script) that sets it in that terminal, or your editor may have a path setting,